# Python regular expression to get the columns and alias and output in sql file

Tags: python, regex

I have a SQL

```
SELECT sys_name AS sys_name
    ,syc_code AS [System Code]
    ,[plcy_cnt]   AS [Policy Count]
    ,[plcy_amt] AS [Policy's Demand]
    ,[insured_ctry_code],
      insured_ctry_desc
     ,sum([Amount (INR - USD)]) AS [Amount (INR - USD)]
    ,[cat_des]   AS [CAT / Desc]
    ,[Address Line.1]
    ,[Office : LP12 Code] AS [Office : LP12 Code]
    ,[Policy-Claim Indicator] AS [Policy-Claim Indicator]
FROM table_name
```

I need to extract the columns as below

```
sys_name,sys_name
syc_code,System Code
plcy_cnt,Policy Count
plcy_amt,Policy's Demand
insured_ctry_code,insured_ctry_code
insured_ctry_desc,insured_ctry_desc
Amount (INR - USD),Amount (INR - USD)
cat_des,CAT / Desc
Address Line.1,Address Line.1
Office : LP12 Code,Office : LP12 Code
Policy-Claim Indicator,Policy-Claim Indicator
```

I am trying to use the pattern

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\[?([\ws_\-\:.]+)\]?\s*(?:AS\s*\[?([\w\s\'\-/:.]+)\]?)?', re.IGNORECASE)
```

but doesn't seem to be working for the first column and columns with : and . in it. I have a code that reads the sql file and extracts the columns and outputs into the csv file. Need some help with the correct regex.

Comment: Does ***[this](https://onecompiler.com/python/422c56pth)*** help?

Comment: Take a look at [sqlglot](https://github.com/tobymao/sqlglot).

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following approach:

[Step1](https://%22%5Cs*(SELECT%7CFROM%7Ctable_name%7Csum)%5Cs*%7C%5B%5C%5B%5C%5D%5D%7C%5E%20*,?%7C,$%22gm):

```
\s*(SELECT|FROM|table_name|sum)\s*|[\[\]]|^ *,?|,$
```

This Step will filter out contents that you don't want except the String `AS`. You should replace the matches with empty.

[Step 2](https://regex101.com/r/wfjqNy/1):
Now replace every `AS` with `,` in the 1st replacement

Python [demo](https://ideone.com/YAz3Uy):

```
import re

regex = r"\s*(SELECT|FROM|table_name|sum)\s*|[\[\]]|^ *,?|,$"
regex2 = r" +AS +"

test_str = ("SELECT sys_name AS sys_name\n"
    "    ,syc_code AS [System Code]\n"
    "    ,[plcy_cnt]   AS [Policy Count]\n"
    "    ,[plcy_amt] AS [Policy's Demand]\n"
    "    ,[insured_ctry_code],\n"
    "      insured_ctry_desc\n"
    "     ,sum([Amount (INR - USD)]) AS [Amount (INR - USD)]\n"
    "    ,[cat_des]   AS [CAT / Desc]\n"
    "    ,[Address Line.1]\n"
    "    ,[Office : LP12 Code] AS [Office : LP12 Code]\n"
    "    ,[Policy-Claim Indicator] AS [Policy-Claim Indicator]\n"
    "FROM table_name")

subst = ""
subst2 = ","

result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    result2=re.sub(regex2, subst2, result, 0, re.MULTILINE)
    if result2:
        print(result2)
```